# Railo DateFormat gives bad result?

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I'm migrating files from Coldfusion 10 to Railo(using Railo Express). I spotted a strange behavior with the DateFormat function. Running the following code:

```
<cfoutput>
  #Dateformat(now(),'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss')#
</cfoutput>
```

In Coldfusion, I get:

```
2014-12-09 01:12:29
```

which is good.

In railo, I get:

```
2014-12-09 hh:12:ss
```

I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: It is DateFormat - not DateTimeFormat. You could use TimeFormat...

Comment: Using DateTimeFormat did it, thanks!

Comment: @da_didi you should write that up as an answer

Comment: Michael - FWIW, your original code does not work correctly in CF10 either, for the same reason. A lot of people overlook the fact the `mm` in `hh:mm:ss` is interpreted as "month" number, NOT "minutes". So the result of that mask is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just so there's a proper answer to this (da_didi and Leigh have both put important info in comments, but not as answers):

In both Railo and ColdFusion `dateFormat()` only formats *dates*. IE: not the time components.

What you need is [`dateTimeFormat()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DateTimeFormat):

```
<cfoutput>
    #dateTimeformat(now(),'yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss')#
</cfoutput>
```

Also note that the mask character for minutes is not `m` but `n` (to disambiguate minutes from months).

You also probably want to use `HH` for hours, otherwise you have an ambiguity between AM and PM times. Or you could suffix the time part with `tt`. Using `HH` is closer to standards though, so is probably preferable.